# Excel change date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have extracted with a macro report that gives me the following date format: JUL13/2023
Is there a way or formula that can transfer it to a regular date format?
I need to track how many days passed from this day to a certain day.

Comment: First of all, ¿are those values text or standard format? Second, if your setup is not englih then JUL is not being recognized as July so you need to create a custom formula to substitute each value to whatever you setup is. You may use IF, SUBSTITUTE or even VLOOKUP with a secondary dataset. You got several options.

Comment: I take data from text file and put it into excel, so it is text format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this test:

```
Function convert_date(date_as_string As String) As Date
    Dim mthstring As String
    mthstring = "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC"
    convert_date = DateSerial( _
    CInt(Right(date_as_string, 4)), _
    CInt(((InStr(1, mthstring, Left(date_as_string, 3)) - 1) / 4) + 1), _
    CInt(Replace(Mid(date_as_string, 4, 2), "/", "")))
End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print convert_date("JUL13/2023")
    Debug.Print convert_date("JUL8/2023")
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Dim var As String
    var = Range("A1").Value
    Range("B1").Value = convert_date(var)
End Sub

Sub test3()
    Dim start_row As Long, end_row As Long, sht As Worksheet
    
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    start_row = 2
    end_row = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each cel In sht.Range("B" & start_row & ":B" & end_row).Cells
        cel.Value = convert_date(cel.Offset(0, -1).Value)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If I get the value from A1, which is JUN13/2023, like var=range(“A1”).value the function gives me type mismatch error, so I am not able to read it from my sheet and convert it. Do you know where the issue might be ?

Comment: Make sure your variable is declared as a string before using it. `Dim var as string` - See `test2()` in edited answer.

Comment: I've just noticed a slight error on my answer and corrected it. Please see revised function.

Comment: Thank you. I just added this function. I am also trying to make a loop to go through each line in column A. And output it to column B. So far I have this logic: N=cells(Rows.count,”A”).end(xlUp).row    J=1   For i=1 to N var=Range(“A”+j).value   Range(“B” + j).value = convert_date(var)   J=j+1      I know there is something wrong in range A and B as getting value as well as outputting them. Just can’t figure it out

Comment: I've added a `Test3()` to the answer to help you with the loop. Any further changes though, will need to be raised as a new question. Good luck!

Comment: That’s very helpful, it was just syntax error on my end. I encouraged different issue. Some of the months comes in French (for example MAI ) in the same format. I tried to modify convert date function by adding French months as well but no luck. Any suggestions I can add that ? There will be 12 months in the same format as English but French : JANV FEVR MARS AVRIL MAI JUIN JUIL AOUT SEPT OCT NOV DEC

Answer (score 0):

This is a formula solution:

`=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),"")),FIND("/",A1,1)-MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),"")))&"/"&LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),""))-1)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,4))`

Comment: You've got a couple of references to `A2` in your formula there.. shouldn't they all be `A1`?

Comment: Thanks - well spotted, left over when testing different parts, now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a helper column. Format it with your preferred date format.

This formula takes advantage of Excel's implicit date conversion:

=(MID(A2,4,2)&LEFT(A2,3)&RIGHT(A2,4))*1

Answer (score 0):

VBA solution:

TextDate = "JUL13/2023"

DateDate = CDate(Left(TextDate, 3) & " " & Mid(TextDate, 4, 2) & " " & Right(TextDate, 4))